# Pure CSS Parallax using Wordpress

Tags: css

I was wondering if it is possible to create a pure css, parallax effect using 4 overlapping layers without using Javascript.  I want the first image to be overlapped by the first block of text as the user scrolls down, and as soon as the gap in the page appears again, i want the second image to overlap the first fixed image. I cant post all of the code but I can provide a URL. Any help would be appreciated.

http://learn.samausa.org/hire/

Answer (score 0):

Keith Clark has managed to achieve this - you can read the blog post here
http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

I'm a joomla user myself, and not familiar with wordpress, but I would imagine you should be able to implement something like this:
html:

```
<div class="parallax">    
    <div class="parallaxLayer firstImage">
        <img src="yourfirstimage" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallaxLayer text">
        <p> Your text goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="parallaxLayer secondImage">
        <img src="yourSecondImage" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parallax{
    perspective:1px;
    height:100vh;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.parallaxLayer{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
.firstImage{
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}
.text{
    transform:translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
.secondImage{
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}
```

There'll of course be some spacing and formatting issues to play with, but that should give you a solid start.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @JohnPaul. I've updated this one, and will be more detailed in the future.